# Android: Как сделать в listview нормальной ширины колонки?

Tags: xml, android, listview

rowlayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp" >
    </TextView>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

и

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >
    </TextView>
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="458dp" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Много что перепробовала, не могу сделать нормальные линии. 
Вот результат:

[ссылка на получившийся результат](http://joxi.ru/2k-UUtg5CbBPQrYtmOs)

```
super.onCreate(cicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_main);
        String[] catnames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label, catnames);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Это все.

Comment: Разметку для list item'а покажите. Адаптер свой или стандартный?

Comment: Вот rowlayout покажите)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gravity  не к списку а к его элементу применить  нужно